# c forward declare (tried like c++ but didn't work)

Tags: c, forward-declaration

A.h

```
#ifndef A
#define A

#include "B.h"

typedef struct {
    B* b;
} A;
void InitA(A* a) {
    a->b=malloc(sizeof(B));
}

#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B
#define B

#include "A.h"

typedef struct {
    A* a;
} B;
void InitB(B* b) {
    b->a=malloc(sizeof(A));
}

#endif
```

I tried like that ,like c++ and typedef.
typedef makes conflict errors between types and previous declare was here and etc.

Thanks.

Comment: First you have duplicate include guards. In `A.h` you also define `B`.

Comment: `#define B` will not work well when your type is called `B`...

Comment: Shouldn't the top file be `#ifndef A`....

Comment: Ops ,it's was just a example for my problem. Thanks anyway. But still in the original code ,there is still errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of fixing it:

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

typedef struct A
{
  struct B* b;
} A;

#include "b.h"

void InitA(A* a)
{
  a->b = malloc(sizeof(B));
}

#endif
```

b.h:

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

typedef struct B
{
  struct A* a;
} B;

#include "a.h"

void InitB(B* b)
{
  b->a = malloc(sizeof(A));
}

#endif
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main(void)
{
  A a;
  B b;
  InitA(&a);
  InitB(&b);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, for `sizeof()` to work, its parameter must be of a known type. In your code `A` and `B` are not yet fully known when you do `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(B)` in `InitA()` and `InitB()`. Rearranging the order of the type definitions, file inclusion and the function definitions can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's go step by step.

Let's see what happens if you want to include one of the files, in this example: `A.h`:

- `A.h` will include `B.h`
- `B.h` will include `A.h`, which will be skipped because of the header guard.
- `B.h` uses `A* a;` where A is an unknown type, at this point you will get a compilation error.

You have to forward declare the type like this: `struct A;` (in `B.h`, before the struct definition).

The similar reasoning holds for the other file (`struct B;`)

Comment: It's pretty long http://pastebin.com/V8e4ThnL (DecompileTestApplication_Program.h) http://pastebin.com/C3ezkLzG (MyAnotherProgram.h) errors wrote in the first file.

Comment: you still have to do the forward declaration first! .... typedef just creates an alias, and the original type is still missing.

Comment: When I doing that ,there x2 errors ,but if I write only that forward declaration there is error after function `DecompileTestApplication_Program_Plan2DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram` (expected `)` before `*` token)